# XSL-FOで縦組がしたい

Tags: xsl, xsl-fo

組版で 縦組 横組 と文字方向が異なる場合がありますが、
XSL-FOで縦組をする方法を教えて下さい。

Comment: XSL-FOで文字の進行方向（インラインの進行方向）、行の進行方向（ブロックの進行方向）を制御するのは@writing-modeプロパティです．どのような箇所に対して縦組みをしたいのでしょうか？本文、表のセルの中、それとも横書きの本文中に部分的に縦書きのテキストを入れるなど...

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-jlreq-20080411/ja/#heading0
図1-3　基本版面の設計要素（縦組の例）
図のような本文の縦組みを想定しておりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-jlreq-20080411/ja/#subheading1_1_4 にある例では、本文縦組みでかつ二段組みですので、

```
<fo:region-body writing-mode="tb-rl" column-count="2" column-gap="18pt">
```

としてやる必要があるでしょう．